# What's upwardly mobile equity?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The definition of *upwardly mobile* is "moving or able to move to a higher social class". However, this meaning doesn't make sense with word equity, which means "the value of a company, divided into many equal parts owned by the shareholders", or "the value of a property after you have paid any mortgage or other charges relating to it". Because the combination is confusing to me. How could valued thing get a higher social class?

So what does *upwardly mobile equity* mean?

Answer (score 2):

*Upwardly mobile* simply means *moving up* (mobile -> moving, upwardly -> in an upward direction).  When a person is described as upwardly mobile it can refer to social classes, as you say, but you could also use it to literally describe someone who was moving upward.

So *upwardly mobile equity* means *equity that is moving in an upward direction*. So the equity is increasing. It's as simple as that :)

Answer (score -1):

"Equity" in this context, means "a chance." A lottery ticket, if you will.

Upwardly mobile equity would therefore mean, "a **chance** of upward mobility."

Example: A person will win $1000 if he correctly guesses head or tails on a coin flip (a 50-50 chance). His **equity** is .50 * $1000 or $500 (50% of $1000). It' not the whole $1000 because there is a 50% chance he won't guess right.

Likewise, a poor person who has a good education and is well spoken has "upwardly mobile equity." S/he may or may not be upwardly mobile but clearly has a chance.

Comment: Well, from the dictionary it has the meanings of "the value of a company, divided into many equal parts owned by the shareholders", or "the value of a property after you have paid any mortgage or other charges relating to it", but it does not have the meaning - a chance. So it confuses me with the combination of upwardly mobile.

Comment: I don't agree with this.  It simply means that an asset is getting more valuable.

Comment: @canoe: See my example. Equity refers to "shares" of a companhy" but can also refer to "shares" of a probability, with "heads" and tails" having an equal share of a coin flip;.